# Progress bar with remaining execution time sas

Tags: progress-bar, sas, execution-time

Is it possible in SAS to create a progress bar, which is able to calculate the percentage/time remaining executing a program?

Comment: Anything in programming is possible, given enough time, money and effort.  See http://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug92/NESUG92034.pdf for an example.

Comment: Robert's answer is one good (though dated!) answer.  A few questions to guide you to other possibilities: Do you have SAS/AF licensed?  What is your program doing?  Are you primarily concerned with data step run times, PROC run times, or something else?  Are you running in Enterprise Guide or in Display Manager?

Comment: Thank's Robert.
Answers to Joe:
I do have SAS licensed. My program is mainly running a lot of do-loops in which I’m e.g. constructing a lot of new datasets. So it’s the time of running these do-loops, I’m most concerned with. And I’m currently running in the SAS 9.3 editor. Don’t know if this helped? Unfortunately I’m not a sas expert – yet!

Comment: SAS/AF, not SAS.  SAS/AF is a module of SAS that lets you make windows and things like that.

Comment: One note; I highly recommend looking at improving your SAS efficiency before you start worrying about process monitors.  "a lot of do-loops constructing a lot of new datasets" is a fairly inefficient way to program in SAS; you should try to minimize the number of datasets you produce, and instead take advantage of SAS features such as BY groups.

Comment: I don't have SAS/AF licensed then, I think :) Thank you for your help, Joe. I need all these new datasets, that's the thing. I'll try to solve the problem by looking at what Robert linked.

Answer (score 6):

One very easy to implement data-step solution is to place log notes.

For example:

```
data test;
set sashelp.class;
do _x = 1 to 10000;
  output;
end;
run;

data want;
set test;
if mod(_n_,1000)=0 then do;
  put "At row " _N_;
end;
run;
```

The second dataset is the one of interest.  It puts a log message every thousand rows.

Comment: And you could also write messages to the log in between steps.  That way if you know the structure of your program, you might know what it means to be at "1st Proc Means of Iteration #561"...if you have 1000 iterations, you are about 50% done.

Answer (score 0):

There is one here with an example of calling it from SAS.

http://www.devenezia.com/downloads/ppb/